# <%= How to write out a String MVC.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC, if I have some content on the page I can do the following:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink(..Blah Blah..)%>
```

How can I acheive the same result in the following block:

```
if(a==b)
{
   Html.Encode("output some text here");
}
```

I want to do this without a lot of tags, hence why I am asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<% if(a==b) {
  Response.Write(Html.Encode("output some text here"));
}%>
```

Answer (score 5):

`<%= ... %>` is just a shortcut for `<% Response.Write(...); %>`.

Answer (score 4):

```
<%= a==b ? Html.Encode("output some text here") : string.Empty %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <% If(a==b){%>
   <% = Html.Encode("output some text here");%>    
 <% }%>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to "drop" out of code and into the markup by closing the code with %> and then restarting the code block after your text with <%

For example:

```
if (a == b)
{
    %>output some text here<%
}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid a tag soup.

Answer (score 0):

in MVC 4, simply use the following:

```
 @if (x == y)
       {
         @Html.Encode('This is Just text')
       }
```